# How do we shuffle an array of radio buttons so that we can randomly click one

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, radio-button, shuffle

I've got a set of radio button and part of our testing procedure we've got to manually click the radio buttons' in some type of random way.

It does not have to be any specific radio button that is clicked; however, in each row either the top of bottom radio must be selected.

I tried it with the JS code below but it does not where.

Help Help!

**Here is my code:**

[image: Radio Buttons and HTML Table]

```
        setTimeout(function() {


        var radios=  document.body.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]'),
            first =false;

        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {

            if (first) {
                radios[i].click();
                first = false;
            } else {
                radios[i+1].click();
                first =true ;
            }
        }

    } , 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the fisher-yates shuffle. Do not implement your own.

http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html

Comment: And what is the "*[Fisher-Yates] shuffle*"? Why should it be used? Why should the OP not "*implement [his] own*"? How should this Fisher-Yates shuffle be used? As written, while I appreciate that you can't yet comment everywhere, this would seem to be a comment, or - at best - a link-only answer with not useful explanation.

Comment: Is any arbitrary RNG not sufficient?

Comment: Dude, that page is more confusing than the questions

Answer (score 0):

**Your radio button names are WRONG.**

If you want a radio either the top of bottom radio to be selected, you should name the radios differently. The way you do right now, all the radios in the top row are in one group and the bottom row is in another group. So, you end up selecting only one in each "row" and not in each "column" as you're expecting.

HTML CODE:-

```
<table>
  <tr> <td>
      <input type="radio" name = "one">
      <input type="radio" name = "two">
      <input type="radio" name = "three">
      <input type="radio" name = "four">            
      <input type="radio" name = "five">
    </td></tr>
    <tr> <td>
      <input type="radio" name = "one">
      <input type="radio" name = "two">
      <input type="radio" name = "three">
      <input type="radio" name = "four">            
      <input type="radio" name = "five">
    </td></tr>      
</table>
```

The `getRandom()` function returns 0 or 1 randomly. We use this to pick the 0th or 1st element having the same name. As the radio buttons are grouped by their name attribute, fetch a random element of the group elements array and set its `checked` attribute to `true`.

Javascript code:

```
    function getRandom(){
      if(Math.random() > 0.5)
        return 1;
      else 
        return 0;  
    }

    document.getElementsByName("one")[getRandom()].checked = true;
    document.getElementsByName("two")[getRandom()].checked = true;
    document.getElementsByName("three")[getRandom()].checked = true;
    document.getElementsByName("four")[getRandom()].checked = true;
    document.getElementsByName("five")[getRandom()].checked = true;
```

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ec7pd9br/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code implemented at Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/mnVZHyaw7ZuYinnHhIHq?p=preview
The important code is in the script.js.  It will run when the page loads or you can run the randomizer and see a random radio button selected by clicking the Run Again button.
I only placed 4 radios on there, you can easily do more.

[image]

```
 <table>
      <tr><td><input type="radio" id="11" /><input type="radio" id="12"  /></td></tr>
      <tr><td><input type="radio" id="21" /><input type="radio" id='22' /></td></tr>

    </table>

(function(){
randomSelect();

})();

function randomSelect()
{
  // unselect all
  var allSelectors = ['11', '12', '21', '22'];
  for (s in allSelectors)
  {
    $("#"+allSelectors[s]).prop('checked',false);
  }
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1  
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) + 1  
console.log(y);

var selector = "#"+x+y;
console.log(selector);
$(selector).prop('checked', true); 
}
```